# Forwarding request to html file when file exists on IBM HTTP Server (with dynamicRouting enabled)

Tags: websphere-liberty, dynamic-routing, ibmhttpserver

I have a configuration where I'm rewriting request to a %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/break/break_on.html when %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/break/break_on.enable file exists.
Look at CONDITION NR1

DocumentRoot /opt/IBM/HTTPServer/htdocs
RewriteEngine On

```
# CONDITION NR1
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/break/break_on.html -f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/break/break_on.enable -f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !break/break_on.html
RewriteRule (.*) /break/break_on.html [PT,L]
```

This was always working with traditional WebSphere. Now since I have WebSphere Liberty with dynamicRouting enabled, the dynamicRouting is sending a request to WebSphere Liberty Servers instead of rediricting it to local %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/break/break_on.html

Status line for URI [/break/break_on.html] client port [60960] transport [libertyController:9080]:   HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46640] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG: Reading response headers for URI [/break/break_on.html] client port [60960] transport [libertyController:9080]:

Look at http_plugin.log:

```
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46208] 00013a65 30094700 - ODR:INFO: http.summary: [0x7f8604008920] RESPONSE_SENT Initial 20.45.100.115 GET HTTP/1.1 http://break/break_on.html?v=2 libertyNode:9080 0 404 5ms 9ms
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46209] 00013a65 30094700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrHttpContextSetStateInternal: exit
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46210] 00013a65 30094700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrHttpContextRelease: deleting proxy=0x7f8604008bb0 delegate=0x7f8604008920
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46211] 00013a65 30094700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrHttpContextRelease: enter - ctx=0x7f8604008920
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46212] 00013a65 30094700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrHttpContextClean: enter - ctx=0x7f8604008920
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46213] 00013a65 30094700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrTargetSelector.tsLockObtain: ts=0x7f8624000c40 obtained lock=0x7f8624000cf0 (heldBy=NOBODY) for tsTargetInfoDecrementRefCnt
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46214] 00013a65 30094700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrTargetSelector.tsTargetinfoDecrementRefCnt: sapp 0x7f862415ef50, tep 2, server 2, node 2, cluster 5, cell 3
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46215] 00013a65 30094700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrTargetSelector.endPointDelete: Releasing reference to endpoint /cell/defaultCollective/node/libertyNode,%2Fapp%2FIBM%2FLiberty%2Fusr/server/srv_libertyApp_1/transport/Http; refcnt=2
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46216] 00013a65 30094700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrTargetSelector.serverDelete: release /cell/defaultCollective/node/libertyNode,%2Fapp%2FIBM%2FLiberty%2Fusr/server/srv_libertyApp_1 (refcnt=1)
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46218] 00013a65 30094700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrTargetSelector.nodeDelete: node 0x7f86241014a0: release /cell/defaultCollective/node/libertyNode,%2Fapp%2FIBM%2FLiberty%2Fusr (refcnt=1)
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46219] 00013a65 30094700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrTargetSelector.cellDelete: cell 0x7f862406bb70: release /cell/defaultCollective (refcnt=2)
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46220] 00013a65 30094700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrTargetSelector.tsLockRelease: ts=0x7f8624000c40 released lock=0x7f8624000cf0 (heldBy=tsTargetInfoDecrementRefCnt)
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46221] 00013a65 30094700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrHttpContextClean: exit
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46222] 00013a65 30094700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrHttpContextSetStateInternal: enter - ctx=0x7f8604008920, state=CACHED, url=
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46223] 00013a65 30094700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrHttpContextSetStateInternal: exit
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46223] 00013a65 30094700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrRoutingInfoRelease: enter - ri=0x7f86240008e0
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46224] 00013a65 30094700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrRoutingInfoRelease: refCount=2, ri=0x7f86240008e0
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46225] 00013a65 30094700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrRoutingInfoRelease: exit
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46226] 00013a65 30094700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrHttpContextRelease: exit
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46637] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG: Status line for URI [/break/break_on.html] client port [60960] transport [libertyController:9080]:   HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46640] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG: Reading response headers for URI [/break/break_on.html] client port [60960] transport [libertyController:9080]:
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46641] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG:    X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46642] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG:    Content-Type: text/html
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46643] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG:    $WSEP:
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46644] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG:    Date: Sat, 11 Feb 2023 15:49:47 GMT
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46645] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG:    Last-Modified: Wed, 04 Jan 2023 14:12:12 GMT
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46646] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG:    Content-Length: 2109
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46647] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG:    Content-Language: en-US
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46648] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG:    Connection: Close
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46649] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrHttpContextSetStateInternal: enter - ctx=0x7f86140028f0, state=RESPONSE_ARRIVED, url=
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46650] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrHttpContextPerformResponseProcessing: wsptHdr=null, partitionVerHdr=null
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46651] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG: getResponseSessionCookie: Checking if session cookie JSESSIONID is present in the response
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46652] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG: getResponseSessionCookie: No session cookie found in the response
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46653] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG: getCookieValue: cookieHeaderValue=null
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46653] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG: getRequestSessionCookieValue: Checking if session cookie JSESSIONID is present in the request
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46655] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG: getRequestSessionCookieValue: No session cookie found in the request
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46656] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrTargetSelector.tsLockObtain: ts=0x7f8624000c40 obtained lock=0x7f8624000cf0 (heldBy=NOBODY) for tsServerApplicationDecrementOutstandingRequestCount
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46657] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG: hmCheckHealthPolicies: Server='/cell/defaultCollective/node/libertyController,%2Fapp%2FIBM%2FLiberty%2Fusr/server/srv_libertyApp_2' avgRT=10 timeoutPct=0
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46658] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrTargetSelector.tsLockRelease: ts=0x7f8624000c40 released lock=0x7f8624000cf0 (heldBy=tsServerApplicationDecrementOutstandingRequestCount)
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46659] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrHttpContextSetStateInternal: exit
[11/Feb/2023:16:49:47.46665] 00013a65 30115700 - ODR:DEBUG: odrHttpContextSetStateInternal: enter - ctx=0x7f86140028f0, state=RESPONSE_SENT, url=
```

So it's obvious that I get 404, this resource doesn't exist on libertyNode, it exists where I have IBM HTTP Server installed.

How can I make sure, that all request are going to %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/break/break_on.html when %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/break/break_on.enable file exist on localhost instead of going to WebSphere Liberty Controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the URL shares a context root with a deployed application, you'll have to get the websphere plugin to decline handling it and let it defer to the  default static file handler (very low priority):

The `skipwas` environment variable is the flexible way to handle this:

```
   RewriteRule (.*) /break/break_on.html [PT,L,E=skipwas:1]
```

I don't think there's a tWAS vs Liberty difference here, or even dynamic routing. I think you were mapping your applications differently (or inadvertently have an application mapped to /)

Comment: Woww, the solution was so easy, thank you!